# How to get Only selected node in Antd Tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, tree, antd

I'm using Antd and I want to create a second Tree with all Checked nodes in the First Tree,
[Take a look here please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK2DL.png)

When i click on the Validate button, a new Tree Shouls be showed and contain only selected fields in the parent one.
How Can i Achieve it ?
Code : https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-browser-glh4n?file=/index.js

Thanks!

Comment: In the codebox link, was unable to find the 'Validate' button (which is shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK2DL.png))

Comment: I just edited my sandbox now,sorry :)

Comment: There are several smaller problems that need to be resolved in order to achieve the stated objective (display 'only selected' on the new-tree when clicking 'Validate'). Firstly, a state variable to enable/disable display of this second/new tree. Next, conditional rendering of JSX for second-tree (only when the variable is set to 'true'). These are the simple ones. More complex ones in next comment.

Comment: When trying to get the `onSelect` to execute, the tab/browser becomes unresponsive. The stated objective is to show only `selected` fields (and not `checked`). Next, if we need to show a tree and we only have the `selected` fields and if those were the leaf-nodes - the structure from the root-node till the leaf-node still needs to be rendered. This would mean tracing the path from root to each `selected` field. Also, it seems that only 1 field may be `selected` at a time (even though multiple are `checked`).

Comment: Hello, I have already do the state of enable/disable display the second Tree, Now i just want to console.log the selected/halfChecked data, then i will create another Tree data :)